# Objective c - Deleting rows of a table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

it's my first question in this awesome site. I've really searched a lot and yet find an answer to the next problem.

I have a table view with 9 cells. One of the cells has a switch button in it. When the switched button value changes, i want to delete 2 rows of the table view. I have written the next code:

```
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"%@", ([switch isOn]) ? @"ON" : @"OFF"); 

NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                             nil];

UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)self.view;

[tableView beginUpdates];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
// I Have to change the number of rows in the section here.

[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

When i run this, I'm getting a problem relating to the number of rows in the section - this number has been changed so i need to change it. I really can't find how i change it, but i know where i have to change it (see code).

How can i do it? how can i call the method `numberOfRowsInSection:NSInteger` and set also the rows?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of rows in the table is in your

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You need this to match the *new* number of rows in the table

---- EDIT

This means that you will need to keep track of the number of rows in your table.

Start with this set to 9 and delete 2 every time you change the switch

```
- (IBAction)switchValueChanged:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"%@", ([switch isOn]) ? @"ON" : @"OFF");

  // We are going to delete 2 rows
  numberOfRows -= 2;
  ...
```

and in your numberOfRowsInSection instead of returning 9 each time, return the new number of rows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: But how can i call this method? i have implemented this method already, setting it to return 9. do i have to implement this method again ?

Comment: See my edit for more details. Basically, you have to return the number of rows in the table _after the delete_ - the table view will call this automatically for you. You're deleting two rows so you need to return 7 instead of 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the data from the datasource not the table cells and then just to refresh the table view. At least this is how i would do the design.

Comment: I don't have a data source, i have created the cells manually. I can't delete them because i have to insert them back later.

Comment: Then you need two arrays of cells - one for the currently visible cells and one for the cells you have deleted. In your switchvaluechanged method move the two cells between the arrays. When you implement numberOfRowsInSection don't return 9, return the number of items in the visible cells array.

Comment: or you can just put a flag on each of your objects: displayTheObject and then (as deanWombourne mentioned) return only the number of the objects without this flag.

Comment: You could have a flag but that might make your cellForRowAtIndex path more complicated - with two arrays you can just say `return [visibleCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to also delete the data from the datasource of the table view. The data source is any container that holds the actual data which is being displayed on the table view. Just deleting the row only deletes the visual item of the row, when tableview is reloaded - it will want to draw 9-2 rows....but since number of rows is still returning 9, it will throw an inconsistency exception and tell you why. See the log carefully.